# Selected random rows and do stuff - select multiple row on range

Tags: excel, vba, range

It seems to be fairly simple but I'm struggling...
I have this simple code to select entire row from a black range of cells, which is totally random, base on the current data.
Because the cells F5 F7 F9 F13 are empty, it selects the entire row.
**So, I wish to change the value from column 1 [A] and 8 [H] to "Estoque", coloured in light blue.**
And I'm stuck on that. Any help, please?

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Columns("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Select
```

[image]

Comment: From your other posts, I see you've made an effort to solve and then asked specific questions. This question though is confusing, vague and too broad. Can you show the code that's trying to do what you want (i.e. write to and change colors of specific cells) and explain what it's not doing what you're aiming for. Otherwise, you're simply asking others here to free write code for you.

Comment: Do you mean that this should happen for every cell that is blank in column `H` and for every corresponding (not necessarily empty) cell in column `A`? Or has the cell in column `A` also to be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A SpecialCells-Intersect Combination

- [`Range.SpecialCells method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)
- [`Application.Intersect method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)
- This will write `Estoque` to all empty cells of column `H` of the used range. It will also write `Estoque` to their corresponding cells (cells in the same row) of column `A`, regardless of whether they are empty.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Estoque()
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rg = Intersect(Range("A:A,H:H"), _
            Columns("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nope!", vbCritical
        'Exit Sub
    Else
        rg.Value = "Estoque"
        MsgBox "Estoque!", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know the Intersect method, I was stuck on ideas. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that when dealing with non-contiguous ranges, you are not able to use `.Resize`, `.Rows`, or `.Columns` successfully. It is usually only `.Cells`, `.Offset`, `.EntireRow` or `.EntireColumn`. So `Intersect` is kind of a savior to remember.

Comment: After several months, the code is runing awesome, but, I wonder to update it with your help. As said before, it writes "Estoque" on blank cells on the intersected range but I'd like  the code to write on the blank cells only if their respective row on column J is >0... if the cell value on column J is negative, it does nothing, if the cell value on column J is positive, it writes "estoque". thanks in advance.